# Redirect whitelisted IP from a php block file?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I use the following php file to ban Ip address that aren't allowed and stop them to access to some files. 
This is the php file

```
<?php


// Get the IP address of the visitor so we can work with it later.
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

// This is where we pull the file and location of the htaccess file. If it's in
// the same directory as this php file, just leave it as is.
$htaccess = '.htaccess';

// This pulls the current contents of your htaccess file so we can search it later.
$contents = file_get_contents($htaccess, TRUE) 
          OR exit('Unable to open .htaccess');

// Lets search the htaccess file to see if there is already a ban in place.
$exists = !stripos($contents, 'deny from ' . $ip . "\n") 
          OR exit('Already banned, nothing to do here.');

// Here we just pull some details we can use later.
$date   = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$uri    = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ENT_QUOTES);
$agent  = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], ENT_QUOTES);
$agent  = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), '', $agent);

// If you would like to be emailed everytime a ban happens, put your email
// INSIDE the quotes below. (e.g. 'my@email.com')
$email = '';

// This is where we can whitelist IP's so they can never be banned. Simply remove 
// the //  from the front of one of the example IP addresses below and add the 
// address you wish to whitelist. Make sure that you leave the single quotes (') 
// intact and the comma at the end. Adding a person to the whitelist AFTER they 
// have been banned will NOT remove them. You must open the htaccess file and 
// locate their ban by hand and remove it.
$whitelist = array(
  // '123.123.123.123',
  // '123.123.123.123',
  // '123.123.123.123',
);


// This section prevents people from being sent to this script by mistake
// via a link, image, or other referer source. If you don't want to check
// the referer, you can remove the following line. Make sure you also
// remove the ending } at the very end of this script.
if (empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {

// This section will write the IP address to the htaccess file and in turn
// ban the address. It will however check the whitelist above to see if
// should be banned.
  if (in_array($ip, $whitelist)) {

    // User is in whitelist, print a message and end script.
    echo "Hello user! Because your IP address ({$ip}) is in our whitelist,
    you were not banned for attempting to visit this page. End of line.";

  } else {

    // User is NOT in whitelist - we need to ban em...
    $ban =  "\n# The IP below was banned on $date for trying to access {$uri}\n";
    $ban .= "# Agent: {$agent}\n";
    $ban .= "Deny from {$ip}\n";

    file_put_contents($htaccess, $ban, FILE_APPEND) 
          OR exit('Cannot append rule to .htaccess');

    // Send email if address is specified
    if (!empty($email)) {
      $message = "IP Address: {$ip}\n";
      $message .= "Date/Time: {$date}\n";
      $message .= "User Agent: {$agent}\n";
      $message .= "URL: {$uri}";

      mail($email, 'Website Auto Ban: ' . $ip, $message);
    }

    // Send 403 header to browser and print HTML page
    header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden', TRUE);
    echo '<html><head><title>Error 403 - Banned</title></head><body>
    <center><h1>Error 403 - Forbidden</h1>Hello user, you have been 
    banned from accessing our site. If you feel this ban was a mistake, 
    please contact the website administrator to have it removed.<br />
    <em>IP Address: '.$ip.'</em></center></body></html>';

  }

}
```

And this is the .htaccess

```
<FilesMatch 403.shtml>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow From All
</FilesMatch>

RewriteEngine On

## #######################! WARNING !########################## ##
## Make SURE you read the following rewrite rules to make sure  ##
## that none of them affect your actual site and to make sure   ##
## they are not blocking real, needed files or folders.         ##
## ############################################################ ##

## Keep the following for added security against snooping ##
RewriteRule ^phpmyadmin /block.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^README /block.php [NC]

## Unless you use your cgi-bin, keep the following ##
RewriteRule ^cgi-bin/formemail.cgi /block.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^cgi-bin /block.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^cgi-bin/(.*)$ /block.php [NC]

## Remove the following if you ARE using WordPress ##
RewriteRule ^wp-admin /block.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^wp-content /block.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes /block.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^wp-config /block.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^wp-cron /block.php [NC]

## Remove the following if you ARE using phpBB ##
RewriteRule ^adm /block.php [NC]

## Remove the following if you ARE using Magento ##
RewriteRule ^var /block.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^app /block.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^downloader /block.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^pkginfo /block.php [NC]

## Remove the following if you ARE using Moodle ##
RewriteRule ^auth /block.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^backup /block.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^grade /block.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^iplookup /block.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^message /block.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^mnet /block.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^plagiarism /block.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^webservices /block.php [NC]

############### START BANS ###############
```

Maybe is something silly, but I need your help, I need that all the ip in the whitelist array to be redirect and not to show the message that is showing at the time.
Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: banning IP's is pointless. easy to change IP , 1 IP can be many people ..

Comment: @Dagon I don't think is so pointless, but thanks for your comment.

Comment: what do you think you achieve? i can get around any IP blocking you put in place

Comment: Surely, using something like this is more efficient & maintainable the actually altering the .htaccess files (which I'd normally disallow for the webserver anyway): http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/access.html#host-deny

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
// User is in whitelist, print a message and end script.
echo "Hello user! Because your IP address ({$ip}) is in our whitelist,
you were not banned for attempting to visit this page. End of line.";
```

Just do:

```
header("Location: /place-to-redirect");
exit();
```

Comment: If i do this i get a redirect loop

Comment: @laviku Then you can try just to include the file, say something like: `include("place-to-redirect");` Since you're routing everything to `block.php` regardless of what the IP is, `block.php` is going to need to know how to serve the pages for someone who is whitelisted. And I guess externally redirecting isn't going to work. Your other option is using mod_rewrite to block IPs for you

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do it the easy way?

```
$allowed = array(
    'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
);
if ((in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $allowed))==false) { header("Location: http://www.domain.com/blocked"); }else{

    echo "You're in!";

}
```